# How to mutate variable with tidyevaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

I'm trying to create a function that prints a plot when user inputs data and variables what to plot. My current problem is that group/subgroup columns may be numeric so I need to mutate them into factors before plotting. I'm trying to do it with this:

```
create_plot <- function(df, group, subgroup, y){
  df %>% 
    select({{group}}, {{subgroup}}, {{y}}) %>% 
    mutate({{group}} = as.factor({{group}})) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x={{subgroup}}, y={{y}}, color={{group}}))
  }

create_plot(sales, YEAR, COUNTRY, VALUE)
```

But it gives an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    select({{group}}, {{subgroup}}, {{y}}) %>% 
    mutate({{group}} ="
```

Which leads me to believe mutate shouldn't be used with {{variables}}. How to do this correctly?

Comment: Why do you have `{{}}`?

Comment: Because I don't have variables called group, subgroup and y in my dataframe. My columns are name YEAR, COUNTRY and VALUE. Dropping those gives error " Error: object 'YEAR' not found". Related to tidyevaluation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{col}} :=` on left hand side in `mutate` -

```
create_plot <- function(df, group, subgroup, y){
  df %>% 
    select({{group}}, {{subgroup}}, {{y}}) %>% 
    mutate({{group}} := as.factor({{group}})) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x={{subgroup}}, y={{y}}, color={{group}}))
}
```